# sql query range selection

Tags: mysql, range

Hi i have a table like below

```
year | month | otherdata
2015    1      
2015    1       
2015    3      
2015    4      
2015    4
2016    1
2016    2
2016    2
```

here how do i select all data of (year 2015/month 4 to year 2016/month 2)
i tried following query.

```
select * from `schedule_details` where (`year` >= 2015 and `month` >= 4) and (`year` <= 2016 and `month` >= 2)
```

but its not working. how do i do this? please help

Comment: Don't you want `'month' <= 2` in the second part of your `where` clause?

Answer (score 0):

thanks
Solved the problem

```
Select *
From schedule_details
Where ( year = 2015 And month >= 4 )
    Or ( year > 2015 And year < 2016 )
    Or ( year = 2016 And month <= 2 )
```

is there any other better way?

Comment: I don't think you need the first `OR` condition. There is no way that year can be both greater than 2015 and less than 2016.